# Function duplicate call

Tags: java, multithreading

I've encountered a odd problem, my run() method runs a function twice. What could be the possible reasons? The run() is called from another thread.

```
run()
{
    while(...)
    {
        ...
    }
    function();
}
```

Comment: the only reason is that it's called twice... so you should post the code of the other thread, rather than this one

Comment: Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: I think with multithreading you should expect things to run more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these cases it helps if you print out the stack trace to find out who was the caller or if you could use a debugger just set a breakpoint and check the call tree.

The simplest way to print out the stack trace is:

```
for (StackTraceElement ste : Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()) {
    System.out.println(ste);
}
```